# How to enable Horizontal scroll on html page

Tags: html, css

I tried to enable horizontal scroll but I couldn't do it. Tried too many combination but its still not scrolling.

You can see the my page below:
[image]

I want to start scrolling after field 10.

You can find my html page below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            overflow:auto;
            /*width: 120%;*/
        }

        div.columnTitle {
            /*font-size: 15px;
            font-family: 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            font-weight: bold;*/
            font: normal normal normal 15px / 20px 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            text-align: left;
            /*float: left;*/
            width: 8%;
            display: table-cell;
            color: #045999;
            text-align: center;
            border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
            line-height: 20px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }


        div.filterDate > select {
            webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
            height: 40px;
            /*border: none;*/
            float: left;
            width: 17%;
        }

        div.data {
            float: left;
            width: 6.7%;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Segoe UI Regular", SegoeUI, "Segoe UI";
            color: rgb(49, 95, 162);
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        div.l2name {
            width: 16%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l3name {
            width: 15%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 1%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l4name {
            width: 14%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 2%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l5name {
            width: 13%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 3%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l6name {
            width: 14%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 3%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.row {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin-top: 0.5%;
            line-height: 250%;
        }

        div.pages {
            margin: 1% 1% 0px 0px;
            float: right;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
        }
        /*div.content {
            margin-top:5%;
        }*/

        .content > div:nth-of-type(odd) {
            background: #e0e0e0;
        }
        /*.content > div:nth-of-type(odd):hover {
            background: black;
        }*/

        row:only-child {
            background-color: red;
        }

        button {
            background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 0px;
            opacity: 0.6;
            transition: 0.3s;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }

            button:hover {
                opacity: 1
            }

        div.pagination {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-top: 5%;
            font: normal normal normal 15px / 20px 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
        }

            div.pagination > .pagingLink {
                color: black;
                float: left;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                transition: background-color .3s;
            }

                div.pagination > .pagingLink.active {
                    background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
                    color: white;
                }

                div.pagination > .pagingLink:hover:not(.active) {
                    background-color: #ddd;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

        .data > a {
            background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
            color: white;
            /*padding: 1em 1.5em;*/
            /*padding: 15px,15px;*/
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

            .data > a:hover {
                background-color: #555;
            }

            .data > a:active {
                background-color: black;
            }

            .data > a:visited {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }

        div.nodata {
            background-color: white !important;
            color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 200px;
            /*height: auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;*/
        }
    </style>

   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">



        <div class="filterDate">
            <select>
                <option value="operator='this-year'">Current Year</option>
                <option value="operator='LastYear'">Year - 1</option>
                <option value="operator='last-x-months' value='12'">12 Months</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field1
        </div>

        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field2

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field3

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field4

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field5
        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field6

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field7

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field8

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field9

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field10

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field11

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field12

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field13

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field14

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field15

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field15

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field15

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle">
            Field15

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Also I read too many articles about that but I couldn't find the proper way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: did you try my answer below? did that worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `width`(as per your requirement) and then place a `scroll`.

```css
body {
  /*width: 120%;*/
}

.header {
  width:430px; /* increase or decrease the width as per you requirement */
  overflow-x: auto; /* automatic scroll post 430px which is assigned above.*/
}

.columnTitle {
  /*font-size: 15px;
            font-family: 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            font-weight: bold;*/
  font: normal normal normal 15px / 20px 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
  text-align: left;
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 8%;
  display: table-cell;
  color: #045999;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.filterDate>select {
  webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  height: 40px;
  /*border: none;*/
  float: left;
  width: 17%;
}

div.data {
  float: left;
  width: 6.7%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI Regular", SegoeUI, "Segoe UI";
  color: rgb(49, 95, 162);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.l2name {
  width: 16%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
  color: #315fa2;
  border-left: solid;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div.l3name {
  width: 15%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
  color: #315fa2;
  margin-left: 1%;
  border-left: solid;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div.l4name {
  width: 14%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
  color: #315fa2;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border-left: solid;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div.l5name {
  width: 13%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
  color: #315fa2;
  margin-left: 3%;
  border-left: solid;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div.l6name {
  width: 14%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
  color: #315fa2;
  margin-left: 3%;
  border-left: solid;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div.row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  line-height: 250%;
}

div.pages {
  margin: 1% 1% 0px 0px;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
}


/*div.content {
            margin-top:5%;
        }*/

.content>div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}


/*.content > div:nth-of-type(odd):hover {
            background: black;
        }*/

row:only-child {
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

div.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font: normal normal normal 15px / 20px 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
}

div.pagination>.pagingLink {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

div.pagination>.pagingLink.active {
  background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
  color: white;
}

div.pagination>.pagingLink:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.data>a {
  background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
  color: white;
  /*padding: 1em 1.5em;*/
  /*padding: 15px,15px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.data>a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.data>a:active {
  background-color: black;
}

.data>a:visited {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

div.nodata {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 200px;
  /*height: auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="filterDate">
      <select>
        <option value="operator='this-year'">Current Year</option>
        <option value="operator='LastYear'">Year - 1</option>
        <option value="operator='last-x-months' value='12'">12 Months</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">Field1</div>

    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field2

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field3

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field4

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field5
    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field6

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field7

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field8

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field9

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field10

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field11

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field12

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field13

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field14

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field15

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field15

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field15

    </div>
    <div class="columnTitle">
      Field15

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">

  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got an easy solution for this.

Put an extra style tag with an incremental variable value like below to your `div` tags with `columnTitle` class:

```
<div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 0;">Field1</div>
<div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 1;">Field2</div>
<div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 2;">Field3</div>
<div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 3;">Field4</div>
<div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 4;">Field5</div>
...
```

And add this 3 lines of extra CSS in your `div.columnTitle` selector

```
div.columnTitle
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: calc(var(--i)*8% + 17%);
}
```

This will solve your issue. I posted this answer supposing that every `div` with `columnTitle` class is gonna have the same width. Hope, this helps.

Thanks.

Here is the complete code snippet that is based on the combination of your codes and my suggestions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            overflow:auto;
            /*width: 120%;*/
        }

        div.columnTitle {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: calc(var(--i)*8% + 17%);
            /*font-size: 15px;
            font-family: 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            font-weight: bold;*/
            font: normal normal normal 15px / 20px 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            text-align: left;
            /*float: left;*/
            width: 8%;
            display: table-cell;
            color: #045999;
            text-align: center;
            border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
            line-height: 20px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }


        div.filterDate > select {
            webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
            height: 40px;
            /*border: none;*/
            float: left;
            width: 17%;
        }

        div.data {
            float: left;
            width: 6.7%;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Segoe UI Regular", SegoeUI, "Segoe UI";
            color: rgb(49, 95, 162);
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        div.l2name {
            width: 16%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l3name {
            width: 15%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 1%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l4name {
            width: 14%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 2%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l5name {
            width: 13%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 3%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.l6name {
            width: 14%;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            color: #315fa2;
            margin-left: 3%;
            border-left: solid;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        div.row {
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin-top: 0.5%;
            line-height: 250%;
        }

        div.pages {
            margin: 1% 1% 0px 0px;
            float: right;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
        }
        /*div.content {
            margin-top:5%;
        }*/

        .content > div:nth-of-type(odd) {
            background: #e0e0e0;
        }
        /*.content > div:nth-of-type(odd):hover {
            background: black;
        }*/

        row:only-child {
            background-color: red;
        }

        button {
            background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 0px;
            opacity: 0.6;
            transition: 0.3s;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }

            button:hover {
                opacity: 1
            }

        div.pagination {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-top: 5%;
            font: normal normal normal 15px / 20px 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
        }

            div.pagination > .pagingLink {
                color: black;
                float: left;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                transition: background-color .3s;
            }

                div.pagination > .pagingLink.active {
                    background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
                    color: white;
                }

                div.pagination > .pagingLink:hover:not(.active) {
                    background-color: #ddd;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

        .data > a {
            background-color: rgb(47, 95, 144);
            color: white;
            /*padding: 1em 1.5em;*/
            /*padding: 15px,15px;*/
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

            .data > a:hover {
                background-color: #555;
            }

            .data > a:active {
                background-color: black;
            }

            .data > a:visited {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }

        div.nodata {
            background-color: white !important;
            color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular', 'SegoeUI', 'Segoe UI';
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 200px;
            /*height: auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;*/
        }
    </style>

   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">



        <div class="filterDate">
            <select>
                <option value="operator='this-year'">Current Year</option>
                <option value="operator='LastYear'">Year - 1</option>
                <option value="operator='last-x-months' value='12'">12 Months</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 0">
            Field1
        </div>

        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 1">
            Field2

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 2">
            Field3

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 3">
            Field4

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 4">
            Field5
        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 5">
            Field6

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 6">
            Field7

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 7">
            Field8

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 8">
            Field9

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 9">
            Field10

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 10">
            Field11

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 11">
            Field12

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 12">
            Field13

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 13">
            Field14

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 14">
            Field15

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 15">
            Field15

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 16">
            Field15

        </div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="--i: 17">
            Field15

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace your listing with Bootstrap tables and you are good to go.

[enter link description here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/)

In the "th" area you can add as much as you want and then you will get an horizontal scroll, you can also add your own visual on your tables to match your image as shown here.

```
<th scope="col">#</th>
```